# Usando o python para executar o notepad

Tags: python

Como usar o python para abrir o notepad, e depois escrever uma mensagem, e por fim usando o python executar o comando ctrl+z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível usar o [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), que fornece maneiras de controlar o seu mouse e teclado.

Ou executar comandos através do [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html).